# Как исключить элемент с querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка

```js
let elementsAll = document.querySelectorAll('.elements__item');

elementsAll.forEach(element => {

  element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let elementsDropdownAll = document.querySelectorAll('.elements__dropdown');

    elementsDropdownAll.forEach(elementsDropdown => {
      elementsDropdown.classList.remove('elements__dropdown--open');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<ul class="elements">
  <li class="elements__item">
    <div class="elements__dropdown"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="elements__item">
    <div class="elements__dropdown"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="elements__item">
    <div class="elements__dropdown"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

При клике на каждый `.elements__item` нахожу все элементы с классом `.elements__dropdown` и удаляю у них модификатор. Вопрос: как можно сделать, чтобы в переменной `elementsDropdownAll` находились все элементы `.elements__dropdown`, но кроме того, который находится в том блоке, по которому произошел клик?

Comment: В цикл добавьте условие `elementsDropdown !== e.target`. И не забудьте в callback-фунцкии обработчика события параметр  объект события `e`

Comment: Спасибо, это работает. Но как быть, если внутри .elements__item кроме .elements__dropdown есть еще другие дочерние элементы? e.target тогда может указывать уже на другой элемент и в переменную elementsDropdownAll попадут все блоки с классом .elements__dropdown

Answer (score 2):

Пользуйтесь аргументами [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers)

переделайте в `element.addEventListener('click', function(event)`

и посмотрите в `console.log(event.target)` вы получите тот элемент на котором сработало событие, далее имея список, имея элемент на котором сработало событие можете сделать всё что вы задумали

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто у всех удалить класс, а потом текущему елементу добавить его, с использованием ивента, как упоминал Aziz Umarov :

```js
let elementsAll = document.querySelectorAll('.elements__item');

elementsAll.forEach(element => {

  element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let elementsDropdownAll = document.querySelectorAll('.elements__dropdown');

    elementsDropdownAll.forEach(e => e.classList.remove('elements__dropdown--open'));

    this.querySelector('.elements__dropdown').classList.add('elements__dropdown--open');

  });
});
```

```css
.elements__dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.elements__dropdown--open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="elements">
  <li class="elements__item">
    <div class="elements__dropdown">1</div>
  </li>
  <li class="elements__item">
    <div class="elements__dropdown">2</div>
  </li>
  <li class="elements__item">
    <div class="elements__dropdown">3</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```